# How to count days between string date java

Tags: java, datetime

I have dates in variable a and b, like this.
String a = "2016-01-28 21:50";
String b = "2016-01-31 21:49";

How do I count how many days are there between variable a and b?

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, you can use ChronoUnit to achieve this.

Here is an example code snippet for you to consider.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class DaysInBetween {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "2016-01-28 21:50"; 
        String b = "2016-01-31 21:49";


        final DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

        final LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse(a, fmt);
        final LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse(b, fmt);

        final long daysInBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1, d2);

        System.out.println("Number of days in between:" + daysInBetween);

    }
}
```

Comment: iam not using java 8, iam using java 7

Comment: @Teguh In that case, I suggest you use the JSR 310 backport for Java 7.

Comment: I don't think the formats match.  I would check that the default parse method won't read the format the OP uses.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm");
        Date dateObj1 = new Date();
        Date dateObj2 = new Date();
        
        dateObj1 = sdf.parse(a);
        dateObj2 = sdf.parse(b);

Comment: and then i get Thu Jan 28 21:50:00 ICT 2016 | Sun Jan 31 21:50:00 ICT 2016